# MATLAB: Apply lowpass filter on sound signal

Tags: matlab, audio

I am implementing a device to record heartbeats using a stethoscope and condensor microphone. I am able to record the sound as a .wav file. Once I store the wav sound in a matlab variable, how do I pass it through a lowpass filter, say the Savitzky-Golay filter. How would the parameters look like

```
y = sgolayfilt(x,order,framelen)
y = sgolayfilt(x,order,framelen,weights)
y = sgolayfilt(x,order,framelen,weights,dim)
```

These are the ways we can call the filter, where would the .wav variable fit?

Comment: If you google something like, "Matlab lowpass filter example," what do you get?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 You get my duplicate ;) (Caveat: I had to append "noise" and "wav" to the search query, but I wanted to be cheeky).